# Wordpress taxonomy page url rewrite

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have taxonomy `lang` and can choose `en` and `ru` , it's posssible to do when I choose taxonomy `en` page url will be `sitename.com/en/page-name` ? I try use Types plugin but there is not this function, maybe it's possible to write this function by yourself

Answer (score 0):

To get your custom multilanguace solution working, it will take a lot of work. You have to hook get_permalink() function to rewrite correctly the permalinks being outputed to nav menus, content and templates. If I were you, I would opt for a ready solution. Eg. [qTransalte](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate), [WPML](http://wpml.org/) or [Stella](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stella-free/). If there is anything you don't like about these plugins, go ahead and develop your own multilingual plugin, otherwise you're just reinventing the wheel.